# Weird post-installation effects on administrator panel - JOOMLA 3.6

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation

I decided to start new project, so I did clear installation (used MSSQL SERVER as database). Everything was fine and really fast. Front-end page doesn't have any errors or weird effects, but administrator side has many similar errors [warnings]. What is wrong and how can I fix them?

Errors: (someone who can, please edit img tags in)

1. https://img.exs.lv/e/z/ezeliitis/Untitled_3.png
2. https://img.exs.lv/e/z/ezeliitis/Untitled_2.png

I did re-install everything, but that didn't fix it. Also, I think it might be related with MSSQL server, but I've to use it - there's no way around that.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: I'd suggest posting this issue on the [Joomla Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues)

Comment: You have asked the same question in different forms 3 times so far. Please update your original question instead of asking the same question again and again.

Comment: Just try, (in global configuration) Database type mysql to mysqli. Because its driver error. Maybe it will fix your warning

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nobody was able to replicate the issue we we had no feedback from the OP